# android:nextFocusForward is going to the wrong EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on an android project and I am using the `android:nextFocusButton` so the user can press the next button on the soft keyboard to move through EditText without needing to tap each edit text to change the focus.

In the layout I am asking for the users first name and last name, in separate EditText within a Linear Layout which is in horizontal

Then on the next line, in another linear layout, I then ask for the company name. Below is a screenshot to show what I mean.

[image: Basic Screen Layout]

What I am trying to do, is in the first name edit text, the user can press next, which should then switch focus to the last name edit text, they then press next again and it moves to the company edit text.

Instead what is happening, is the first name has focus, the user presses the next button, and it goes to the company edit text instead of the last name.

Below is a snippet of my XML layout

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <EditText android:id="@+id/createAccount_txtFirstName"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="@string/first_name"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/createAccount_txtLastName"/>
                <EditText android:id="@+id/createAccount_txtLastName"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:hint="@string/last_name"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/createAccount_txtCompanyName"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <EditText android:id="@+id/createAccount_txtCompanyName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/company_name"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/createAccount_txtEmail"/>
```

Comment: try to add android:imeOptions="actionNext"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just place this inside your first edittext. Also replace nextFocusForward with **nextFocusDown**

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/createAccount_txtFirstName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="@string/first_name"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/createAccount_txtLastName">
 <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

It seems to be bugged when running this code on the emulator. However, it works on phones

Comment: Changing to nextFocusDown seems to work. I'm not testing on the emulator, using a 2012 Nexus 7.

Comment: nextFocusDown is not a fix but hack, it breaks navigation with D-pad or keyboard, where down key would actually jump to right in your case.

Answer (score 5):

It might be that your XML is ignored by Android focus algorithm. Documentation says following:

> In rare cases, the default algorithm may not match the intended
>   behavior of the developer. In these situations, you can provide
>   explicit overrides with the following XML attributes in the layout
>   file: nextFocusDown, nextFocusLeft, nextFocusRight, and nextFocusUp.

I had similar problem and i solved it by using **nextFocusDown**.

More on [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html)

Answer (score 3):

None of the solutions worked for me except for listening for editor action listener and programmatically setting the focus to the next EditText.

```
    mFirstName.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            mLastName.requestFocus();
            return true;
        }
    });
```